# Uncaught Error: No module: firebaseSimpleLogin

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

When I open my website, nothing shows up except in console, it says "Uncaught Error: No module: firebaseSimpleLogin". Without $firebaseSimpleLogin and login/signup functions, my website works well with Firebase.

I am using AngularJS and I have added $firebaseSimpleLogin as a dependency in my module/controller. 
Here is the module:

```
angular.module('flavor', ['flavorServices', 'firebase', 'firebaseSimpleLogin'])
.config(flavorRouter);

function flavorRouter ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/the_part_using_login.html',
        controller: 'the_part_using_login_Ctrl'});
}
```

Here is the controller for the partial html:

```
function the_part_using_login_Ctrl ($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {

    var userAuthRef = new Firebase("https://thenameofmyapp.firebaseio.com/userAuth");
    var loginObj = $firebaseSimpleLogin(userAuthRef);
    $scope.user = loginObj.user;
    $scope.userLogin = function(){
        //login part here
    };
    $scope.userSignup = function(){
        //signup part here
    };
}
```

I have included these files in my index.html in the following order. I am not sure if this order is right:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
<!--Other partial files and controller files-->
```

Another thing to mention is, I am also using nodeJS as my server. I use server to deal with some special files so I don't want to put everything on Firebase Hosting. I am not sure if nodeJS is interfering with $firebaseSimpleLogin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dependencies you have `[..., 'firebase', 'firebaseSimpleLogin']`, but there is no module named firebaseSimpleLogin. It's really as simple as the error message indicates.

Checking out the quickstart for AngularFire, it does not list any additional dependencies when [adding authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-authentication). Simple remove that extraneous dependency and you should be good to go.

For background, a *module* and a *service* are separate concepts. A module can contain several services. The AngularFire module is called `firebase` and it contains the `$firebase`, `$firebaseSimpleLogin`, `$FirebaseArray`, and `$FirebaseObject` service factories.

Also note that `$firebaseSimpleLogin` will go away, and be replaced by `$firebaseUser` in the 0.9 release due out next week.